# Load function from within DOMcontentLoaded scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope, domcontentloaded

**jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ee7oe5pb/2/

**Javascript**

```
var events = (function () {
    var fn = {};
    fn.refresh = function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
    return fn;
})();

var menu = (function () {
    var fn = {};
    fn.init = function(message) {
        events.refresh('Work from the function root'); // Work
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            events.refresh('Work from the domcontentloaded'); // Don't work
        });
    }
    return fn;
})();

menu.init();
```

**Question**

When running `menu.init` it starts the menu init function. It trigger the `events.refresh` functions and gives an alert with a message. That part works perfectly fine.

The `events.refresh` is also called in the `DOMContentLoaded` scope. This is triggered when the page is completely loaded. Now `events.refresh` is `undefined function`. Why? How can I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but think this [link](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/) help you understand. it helped me.
http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/

Answer (score 0):

Running your code on browser works fine(not in jsfiddle).

Check:

1) Make sure if `events` is declared in global context

2) Try to access events as 'windows.events' (in most browsers 'window.event' is reserved, so maybe you should try to use other var name)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  window.events.refresh('Work from the domcontentloaded');
});
```

And to clarify, [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) fires right after when DOM has constructed completely. If you want to handle after page was fully loaded you need to use 'onload'.